# AutoMapper Mocking UnitOfWork failing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, tdd, moq

I am trying to mock the UnitOfWork however I need some help since I am not managing to achieve my results correctly

So I have the following BooksController:-

```
public class BooksController : BaseController
{
    private IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork;

    public BooksController()
    {
        UnitOfWork = new UnitOfWork();
    }

    public BooksController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        UnitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    // GET: api/Books
    public IQueryable<BookDTO> GetBooks()
    {
        return UnitOfWork.BookRepository.GetBooks("").ProjectTo<BookDTO>();
    }
    ...................
```

the following BooksRepository:-

```
public class BooksRepository : IBooksRepository
{
    internal BookContext Context = new BookContext();
    internal DbSet<Book> dbSet;

    public BooksRepository(BookContext context)
    {
        Context = context;
        dbSet = context.Set<Book>();
    }

    public virtual IQueryable<Book> GetBooks(string includeProperties = "")
    {

        IQueryable<Book> query = dbSet;

        foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split
            (new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        {
            query = query.Include(includeProperty);
        }

        return query;
    }
    ...........................
```

the UnitOfWork :-

```
public class UnitOfWork : IDisposable, IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly BookContext _context = new BookContext();
    private IBooksRepository _booksRepository;

    public IBooksRepository BookRepository
    {
        get
        {
            if (_booksRepository == null)
            {
                _booksRepository = new BooksRepository(_context);
            }
            return _booksRepository;
        }

    }
    .........................
```

in Global.asax I have :-

```
AutoMapperConfig.RegisterMappings();
```

The AutoMapperConfig is as follows :-

```
public static class AutoMapperConfig
{
    public static void RegisterMappings()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(x =>
        {
            x.AddProfile<BookMappings>();
        });
    }
}
```

and the BookMappings :-

```
public class BookMappings : Profile
{
    public override string ProfileName => "BookMappings";

    protected override void Configure()
    {
        CreateMap<Book, BookDTO>();
        CreateMap<Book, BookDTO>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.BookTitle,
                opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Title));
        CreateMap<Book, BookDTO>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.AuthorName,
                opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Author.Name));

        CreateMap<Book, BookDetailDTO>();
        CreateMap<Book, BookDetailDTO>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.BookTitle,
                opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Title));
        CreateMap<Book, BookDetailDTO>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.AuthorName,
                opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Author.Name));
        CreateMap<Book, BookDetailDTO>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.GenreType,
                opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Genre.Type));
    }
}
```

and finally the test I wish to run:-

```
[TestFixture]
public class BooksControllerTests
{
    private Mock<IUnitOfWork> _unitOfWorkMock;
    private Mock<IBooksRepository> _booksRepositoryMock;
    BooksController objController;
    List<Book> books = new List<Book>();

    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        _unitOfWorkMock = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
        _booksRepositoryMock = new Mock<IBooksRepository>();
        _unitOfWorkMock.Setup(x => x.BookRepository)
            .Returns(_booksRepositoryMock.Object);
        objController = new BooksController(_unitOfWorkMock.Object);
        AutoMapperConfig.RegisterMappings();

        books = new List<Book>()
        {
            new Book {Id = 1, Title = "Hamlet", ISBN = 1853260096, AuthorId = 1, GenreId = 1, IsAvailable = true, Summary = "Hamlet is not only one of Shakespeare's greatest plays, but also the most fascinatingly problematical tragedy. "},
            new Book {Id = 2, Title = "Macbeth", ISBN = 1853260355, AuthorId = 1, GenreId = 1, IsAvailable = true, Summary = "Shakespeare’s Macbeth is one of the greatest tragic dramas the world has known. "},
            new Book {Id = 3, Title = "Romeo And Juliet", ISBN = 1840224339, AuthorId = 1, GenreId = 2, IsAvailable = true, Summary = "Romeo and Juliet is the world's most famous drama of tragic young love. "}
        };
    }

    [Test]
    public void Get_Post_Should_Get_All_Books()
    {
        // Arrange
        _booksRepositoryMock.Setup(x => x.GetBooks(""))
                            .Returns(books.AsQueryable());

        // Act
        var result = objController.GetBooks().ToList();

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(result.Count, 3);
    }
}
```

I wish to pass the mock list I created in my test to the BooksController and verify that I get back 3 results, however I have not managed to do that.

At the moment it is failing on the Act of Get_Post_Should_Get_All_Books()
and it seems to not find the Automapper and giving the following error:-

System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

at lambda_method(Closure , Book )
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)

Any help will be very much appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to configure your fake UoW(`_unitOfWorkMock`) to return the repository.

Add the following line to your arrange or setup method:

```
 _unitOfWorkMock.Setup(x => x.BookRepository)
                .Returns(_booksRepositoryMock.Object);
```

Comment: I have added that to the setup however I am getting an object is not set to an instance of an object on the Act --             var result = objController.GetBooks().ToList();

Comment: @Johann , I took the code into VS; `UnitOfWork.BookRepository.GetBooks("")` gave me the expected list.... so the problem is with your Automapper configuration since; `.ProjectTo<BookDTO>();`. maybe you are not initialize it....

Comment: I initialized this in the Arrange now AutoMapperConfig.RegisterMappings(); but still getting the error

Comment: The Stack Trace for the GetBooks looks as follows :-  "   at lambda_method(Closure , Book )\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Linq.SystemCore_EnumerableDebugView`1.get_Items()"

Comment: However yes I confirm its the AutoMapper that is not working, since removeing the ProjectTo works fine.  Am I not initializing it well with AutoMapperConfig.RegisterMappings()?

Comment: @Johann I am not sure... Last time I had to use AutoMapper was more then 2 years ago... According to [this article](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Queryable-Extensions) you have to use `CreateMap` method...

Comment: that is how I am doing my mapping :(  OK thanks will keep on trying

Comment: Replacing `.ProjectTo` with `Mapper.Map` could help

Answer (score 0):

After reading some posts which do not suggest Automapper especially with TDD, I decided to remove Automapper altogether.